# I am shades off meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning

I : You look like xxx

Girl : lol I'm a little shades off haha

I looked up google and dictionary but can't find any definition.

What does that mean?

Comment: I've never heard the expression (which doesn't mean people don't use it).  But from context it sounds just to mean "I'm not feeling so great today."  It's important to give context of where you see such statements, because it could be something one person made up, or someone's [auto-correct](http://www.damnyouautocorrect.com/) failing--and it's easier to address that when we know where it comes from.

Comment: Perhaps it just means "Girl" isn't a native speaker. We really need a bit more context.

Comment: Was "xxx" a person's name and did the girl say "a **few** shades off".

Answer (score 2):

I've heard this before, to mean that someone isn't feeling 100% for some reason:

> *I am a little off today*...

I've heard this synonymous expression as well:

> *I am a shade off today*...

However, I've never seen *little* modify *shade* before, (at least, not in this context):

> <strike>I am a little shade off today</strike>...

nor have I ever seen *shade* pluralized in this context:

> <strike>I am shades off today</strike>...

---

Some relevant quotes:

> I've been just a shade off with that driver and was a shade off today.
>   <sup>(Golfer Russ Cochran, in an [interview](http://www.pgatour.com/champions/news/2011/02/19/cochran-transcript.html))</sup>
>
> Everything feels a little off right now. Everything feels a little strange right now. It is going to take time.
>   <sup>(Baseball player Alex Rodriguez, as quoted in the [New York Post](http://nypost.com/2015/03/04/a-rod-opens-2015-with-a-hit-to-the-delight-of-the-crowd/))</sup>